# Constructing a Seismic Tripartite Graph with TikZ & pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am attempting to use [`TiKZ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd?lang=en) and [`pgfplots`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots?lang=en) to construct a seismic tripartite graph.  These are used by structural engineers to determine seismic response for a structure.  The example I am attempting to replicate is pasted below.  This is related to [my post is Engineering.SE](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8760/generating-a-blank-seismic-tripartite-graph), for those interested.

[image: example tripartite]

My working example is pasted below.

```
\documentclass[letter,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,%
    left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,%
    footskip=.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Primary Axes
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        %
        width=9in, height=7in,
        title=Tripartite Paper,
        % Frequency Axis
        xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
        xmin=0.1, xmax=1000,
        domain=1:1000, 
        log ticks with fixed point,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
        % Pseudovelocity Axis
        ylabel={Pseudo Response Velocity (in/sec)},
        ymin=0.01, ymax=10,
        domain=1:100, 
        log ticks with fixed point,
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
        grid=minor
        ]

    \end{loglogaxis}

    % Secondary Axes
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        % Pseudoacceleration Axis
        xlabel={Acceleration (g)},
        xlabel style={rotate=45,anchor=north},
        xmin=0.0001, xmax=100,
        domain=0.0001:100, 
        rotate=45,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        x tick label style={rotate=-45, anchor=west, /pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
        % Displacment Axis
        ylabel={Displacement (in)},
        ylabel style={rotate=-135,anchor=south},
        ymin=0.000001, ymax=10,
        domain=0.000001:10, 
        log ticks with fixed point,
        y tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, /pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
        grid=minor
        ]

    \end{loglogaxis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This generates the following graph, which has some obvious issues.

[image: my graph]

The things that I can't figure out how to fix are:

1. Remove the border from the secondary axes
2. Have the secondary axes extend beyond the extents of the primary axes (ideally ad infinitum with an anchor point at a specific place)
3. Keep all the major axis gridlines square and the same size
4. Put the secondary axis labels above the major gridlines (see example)
5. Move the secondary axis tick labels in the middle of the graph

Comment: can you explain how are built the tilting axes and scale of these axes

Comment: @rpapa, not quite sure what you mean.  The secondary axes are at a 45-deg skew to the primary axes, as in the first image.  Ideally, I'd like to anchor the secondary axes coordinate (0.01,0.001) to the primary axes coordinate (10,0.1).  For scale, the secondary axes are scaled such that the spacing of the primary axes between 10^n times cos(45deg) equals the spacing of the secondary axes between 10^n.  If that makes sense...it's hard to put in writing.

Comment: In other words, the _diagonal_ of the square made by the major gridlines of the secondary axes is the same length as the distance between major gridlines on the primary axes.

Comment: Your best bet is just to draw all the diagonals and label them with node[mid].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally worked out a solution to this problem and thought others might benefit.  The MWE is included at the bottom.  Any suggestions to make it more concise are greatly appreciated.  Likely this could be shortened in the .tex file by exporting a lot of the information to an external .csv file.  As this process was a bit involved, I'm providing a link to a [post on my website](https://www.glennfrazee.com/eng-tools/tripartite-paper) for the details involved in generating such a graph.

[image: tripartite paper]

```
\documentclass[letter,landscape]{article}

\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.2in,%
    left=0.5in,right=0.5in,top=0.5in,bottom=0.5in,%
    footskip=.25in]{geometry}
    
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/360668/make-a-white-background-behind-pgfplots-node-label
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
% define the length of the contour lines
\contourlength{0.3em}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\tikzset{every axis plot/.append style={solid,mark=none}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    % Primary Axes
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        %
        width=9in, height=7in,
        title=Tripartite Paper,
        samples=2,
        % Frequency Axis
        xlabel={Frequency (Hz)},
        xmin=0.1, xmax=1000,
        domain=0.1:1000, 
        log ticks with fixed point,
        x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
        % Pseudovelocity Axis
        ylabel={Pseudo Response Velocity (in/sec)},
        ymin=0.01, ymax=10,
        %range=0.01:10, 
        %restrict y to domain =0.009:11,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        y tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
        grid=minor
        ]
        %
    %Pseudoacceleration Lines
    \addplot[gray]{0.00001*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00002*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00003*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00004*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00005*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00006*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00007*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00008*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00009*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.0001*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0002*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0003*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0004*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0005*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0006*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0007*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0008*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0009*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.001*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.002*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.003*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.004*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.005*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.006*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.007*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.008*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.009*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.01*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.02*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.03*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.04*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.05*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.06*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.07*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.08*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.09*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.1*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.2*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.3*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.4*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.5*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.6*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.7*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.8*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{0.9*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{1*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{2*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{3*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{4*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{5*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{6*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{7*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{8*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{9*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{10*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{20*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{30*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{40*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{50*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{60*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{70*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{80*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{90*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{100*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    \addplot[gray]{200*386.09/(2*3.1415*x)};
    %
    %
    %Dispacement Lines
    \addplot[gray]{0.000002*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.000003*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.000004*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.000005*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.000006*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.000007*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.000008*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.000009*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.00001*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00002*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00003*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00004*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00005*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00006*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00007*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00008*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.00009*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.0001*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0002*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0003*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0004*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0005*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0006*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0007*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0008*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.0009*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.001*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.002*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.003*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.004*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.005*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.006*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.007*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.008*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.009*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.01*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.02*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.03*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.04*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.05*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.06*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.07*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.08*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.09*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{0.1*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.2*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.3*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.4*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.5*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.6*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.7*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.8*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{0.9*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{1*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{2*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{3*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{4*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{5*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{6*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{7*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{8*2*3.1415*x};
    \addplot[gray]{9*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    \addplot[gray]{10*2*3.1415*x};
    %
    %
    %Line Markers
    %Acceleration values
    \addplot [
        nodes near coords={
            \contour{white}{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        },
        only marks,
        mark=none,
        visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,
        every node near coord/.style={anchor=\alignment, color=black, font=\footnotesize, rotate=-45},
        point meta=explicit symbolic]
    table [meta index=2]{
        x       y       label   alignment
        0.29        3.6     {Displacement (in)} 0
        965.09432   6.36706   {100}   0
        863.2066   5.69487   {80}   0
        747.55884   4.9319   {60}   0
        610.37924   4.02688   {40}   0
        431.6033   2.84744   {20}   0
        305.18962   2.01344   {10}   0
        272.96989   1.80088   {8}   0
        236.39886   1.5596   {6}   0
        193.01886   1.27341   {4}   0
        136.48495   0.90044   {2}   0
        96.50943   0.63671   {1}   0
        86.32066   0.56949   {0.8}   0
        74.75588   0.49319   {0.6}   0
        61.03792   0.40269   {0.4}   0
        43.16033   0.28474   {0.2}   0
        30.51896   0.20134   {0.1}   0
        27.29699   0.18009   {0.08}   0
        23.63989   0.15596   {0.06}   0
        19.30189   0.12734   {0.04}   0
        13.64849   0.09004   {0.02}   0
        9.65094   0.06367   {0.01}   0
        8.63207   0.05695   {0.008}   0
        7.47559   0.04932   {0.006}   0
        6.10379   0.04027   {0.004}   0
        4.31603   0.02847   {0.002}   0
        3.0519   0.02013   {0.001}   0
        2.7297   0.01801   {0.0008}   0
        2.36399   0.0156   {0.0006}   0
        1.93019   0.01273   {0.0004}   0
        0.4316   0.02847   {0.0002}   0
        0.30519   0.02013   {0.0001}   0
        0.27297   0.01801   {0.00008}   0
        0.2364   0.0156   {0.00006}   0
        0.19302   0.01273   {0.00004}   0
    };
    %
    %Displacement values
    \addplot [
        nodes near coords={
            \contour{white}{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        },
        only marks,
        mark=none,
        visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,
        every node near coord/.style={anchor=\alignment, color=black, font=\footnotesize, rotate=45},
        point meta=explicit symbolic]
    table [meta index=2]{
        x       y       label   alignment
        350     3.8     {Acceleration (g)}  180
        0.10372   6.51689   {10}   180
        0.1133   5.69487   {8}   180
        0.13082   4.9319   {6}   180
        0.16022   4.02688   {4}   180
        0.22659   2.84744   {2}   180
        0.32045   2.01344   {1}   180
        0.35827   1.80088   {0.8}   180
        0.4137   1.5596   {0.6}   180
        0.50667   1.27341   {0.4}   180
        0.71655   0.90044   {0.2}   180
        1.01335   0.63671   {0.1}   180
        1.13296   0.56949   {0.08}   180
        1.30823   0.49319   {0.06}   180
        1.60225   0.40269   {0.04}   180
        2.26592   0.28474   {0.02}   180
        3.20449   0.20134   {0.01}   180
        3.58273   0.18009   {0.008}   180
        4.13698   0.15596   {0.006}   180
        5.06675   0.12734   {0.004}   180
        7.16546   0.09004   {0.002}   180
        10.13349   0.06367   {0.001}   180
        11.32959   0.05695   {0.0008}   180
        13.08228   0.04932   {0.0006}   180
        16.02246   0.04027   {0.0004}   180
        22.65917   0.02847   {0.0002}   180
        32.04491   0.02013   {0.0001}   180
        35.8273   0.01801   {0.00008}   180
        41.3698   0.0156   {0.00006}   180
        50.66745   0.01273   {0.00004}   180
        226.59173   0.02847   {0.00002}   180
        320.4491   0.02013   {0.00001}   180
        358.27299   0.01801   {0.000008}   180
        413.69801   0.0156   {0.000006}   180
        506.67452   0.01273   {0.000004}   180
    };
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

here is my proposal, I am not satisfied but it should allow others to complete.

I do not know what to write about tilting axes

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections} 


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2.5,transform shape]
\def\nbdecade{4}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\fin}{\nbdecade-1}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\decalx}{\nbdecade/2}

\begin{scope}

\def\minx{-1}
\def\maxx{3}
\def\miny{-2}
\def\maxy{2}
\foreach \yy in {\minx,...,\maxx}{
    \foreach \xx in{1,2,4,6,8}{
        \draw[red, name path global/.expanded = X\xx10\yy] ({log10(\xx*10^(\yy)}, {log10(10^(\miny)})node[below=0.5em,scale=1/4,rotate=90]{X\xx10\yy:$\xx \cdot 10^{\yy}$}coordinate(X\xx-\yy) -- ({log10(\xx*10^(\yy)},{log10(10^(\maxy+1)});
    }
}
\foreach \yy in {\miny,...,\maxy}{
    \foreach \xx in{1,2,4,6,8}{
        \draw[blue,name path global/.expanded=Y\xx10\yy] ({log10(10^(\minx)}, {log10(\xx*10^(\yy)})node[left,scale=1/4]{$Y\xx10\yy$:$\xx \cdot 10^{\yy}$}coordinate(Y\xx-\yy) -- (\nbdecade,{log10(\xx*10^(\yy)});
    }
}

\clip (\minx,\miny) rectangle ({\maxx+1},{\maxy+1});
\foreach \yy in {\miny,...,\maxy}{
    \foreach \xx in{1,2,4,6,8}{
        \path[name intersections={of=X1101 and Y\xx10\yy, by= P}];
        %\path[name intersections={of=X1101 and Y110-1, by= P}];
        \draw [thin,green] (P) --+ (45:4)--+(-135:4)node[sloped,pos=0.4,black,scale=1/5]{$\xx10^{\yy}$};
        \draw [thin,purple] (P) --+ (-45:4)--+(135:4)node[sloped,pos=0.6,black,scale=1/5]{$\xx10^{\yy}$};       
}
}

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]