# Make a White Background Behind pgfplots Node Label

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nodes-near-coords

I have a graph I'm trying to display and need to label each coordinate with the given values.  For a couple of the labels, the text overlaps the line.  For just a single line, I could probably move the label position.  However, I typically have multiple lines per graph, so that's not always feasible.

Using my MWE, is there a way to make the background for the node labels white so that the text and the lines don't overlap?  Note that I am using the methodology given in [this previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47692/81543).

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{capt-of}    

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=south east,
        xlabel style={align=center},
        xlabel={Horizontal Subgrade Modulus, (lb/in)/in},
        ymin=600,
        ylabel={Maximum Moment, lb-in (N-m)},
        height=0.3\textheight, 
        width=0.9\columnwidth,
        cycle list name=mark list*,
        legend columns=2
        ]
            \addplot [nodes near coords,mark=*, %S1
                visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,
                every node near coord/.style={anchor=\alignment},
                point meta=explicit symbolic,]
                table [meta index=2]{
                    x   y   label   alignment
                    94  637 {\footnotesize 637 (71.94)} -110
                    185 766 {\footnotesize 766 (86.59)} -90
                    357 885 {\footnotesize 885 (100.02)}    90
                };

        \legend {S1}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{MAXIMUM MOMENT --- 4 IN. DIAMETER PIPE}
    \label{4_Mom}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

[image: graph]

Comment: It looks like adding `\tikzset{every node/.style={fill=white}}` right before `\begin{tikzpicture}` adds the white background, but the padding and positioning leave a lot to be desired.  Maybe something along those lines, but nicer looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it to the nodes that you are placing, through `every node near coord` or to `every node` (for all nodes). Also, you can play with the `inner sep` and `outer sep` to reduce the white space around your labels.

Also, from the previous question, you can play with the `padding` and `xshift` and `yshift` for better positioning.

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=south east,
        xlabel style={align=center},
        xlabel={Horizontal Subgrade Modulus, (lb/in)/in},
        ymin=600,
        ylabel={Maximum Moment, lb-in (N-m)},
        height=0.3\textheight, 
        width=0.9\columnwidth,
        cycle list name=mark list*,
        legend columns=2
        ]
            \addplot [nodes near coords,mark=*, %S1
                visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,
                every node near coord/.style={anchor=\alignment, fill=white},
                point meta=explicit symbolic,]
                table [meta index=2]{
                    x   y   label   alignment
                    94  637 {\footnotesize 637 (71.94)} -110
                    185 766 {\footnotesize 766 (86.59)} -90
                    357 885 {\footnotesize 885 (100.02)}    90
                };

        \legend {S1}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \captionof{figure}{MAXIMUM MOMENT --- 4 IN. DIAMETER PIPE}
    \label{4_Mom}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

Remember to provide packages and document class next time for your [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe).

Comment: Thanks, I noticed the missing packages just a minute ago and added them back in.  Copied/pasted too many times and missed it the last time.

Comment: @grfrazee, I do not understand you logic. so I delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

If you really have "a lot" of other lines with `nodes near coords` in your plot and only want to avoid that the text cannot be written properly, you could also use the [`contour`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/contour/contour.pdf) package to draw the `nodes near coords`, instead of using a white background for nodes as suggested in [adn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/360670/95441). Play with the `\contourlength` so it fits your needs best.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[outline]{contour}
    % define the length of the contour lines
    \contourlength{0.2em}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        legend pos=south east,
        xlabel style={align=center},
        xlabel={Horizontal Subgrade Modulus, (lb/in)/in},
        ymin=600,
        ylabel={Maximum Moment, lb-in (N-m)},
        cycle list name=mark list*,
        nodes near coords={
            % add the contour command to the `nodes near coords' output
            % (change the color to see what really is happening)
            \contour{white}{\pgfplotspointmeta}
        },
        visualization depends on=\thisrow{alignment} \as \alignment,
        node near coords style={
            font=\footnotesize,
            anchor=\alignment,
        },
        point meta=explicit symbolic,
    ]
        \addplot table [meta index=2] {
            x   y   label          alignment
            94  637 {637 (71.94)}  -110
            185 766 {766 (86.59)}  -90
            357 885 {885 (100.02)} 90
        };

        \legend {S1}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]

Comment: Ooh, I like the effect this produces.  Having it contour the individual glyphs instead of a white block in the background is pretty neat.  I'll have to keep this in mind.